# iPhone recursive finish blocks

Tags: iphone, networking, recursion

He there, i have a simple tree structure with files and folders. It's part of a client- server application which can download virtual folders. Anyways i like using ^blocks for async programming. I have 3 urls, the first one downloads a folder description, the second one is for downloading a file and the third one is for downloading a folder contents. DSFolder is the folder description and DSFile inherits from DSFolder and contains a NSData field for the download result. The folder downloading code looks like this:

```
- (void)loadFolderData:(DSFolder *)folder 
              finished:(void(^)(DSFolder *))finished 
                 error:(void(^)(NSError *))error {

    if (!folder) {
        return;
    }
    for (DSFolder* fileOrFolder in folder.children) {
        if ([fileOrFolder isFolder]) {
            [self loadFolderData:fileOrFolder
                        finished:^(DSFolder * folder) {

                        // *********************************
                        // Next folder level would be a copy
                        // of the whole for loop in here
                        // *********************************

                    } error:^(NSError * err) {
                        if (error) {
                            error(err);
                        }
                    }];
        } else {
            [self loadFile:fileOrFolder.name
                    folder:folder.name
                  finished:^(NSData * data) {
                      ((DSFile *) fileOrFolder).data = data;
                  } error:^(NSError * err) {
                      if (error) {
                          error(err);
                      }
                  }];
        }
    }
}
```

Well i could limit the tree level depth by just copying the loop inside a few times, but that seems very ugly. I hope this question is reasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion *already* runs a "copy of the loop" for you:

```
- (void)loadFolderData:(DSFolder *)folder 
              finished:(void(^)(DSFolder *))finished 
                 error:(void(^)(NSError *))error {

    if (!folder) {
        return;
    }
    for (DSFolder* fileOrFolder in folder.children) {
        if ([fileOrFolder isFolder]) {
            [self loadFolderData:fileOrFolder finished:nil error:error];
        } else {
            [self loadFile:fileOrFolder.name
                    folder:folder.name
                  finished:^(NSData * data) {
                      ((DSFile *) fileOrFolder).data = data;
                  } error:error];
        }
    }
}
```

I'm assuming that `-loadFile:finished:error:` correctly handles a nil error-block.

A few other things:

- `[self loadFile:fileOrFolder.name  folder:folder.name ...]` looks like it does the wrong thing if there are subdirectories: Assuming the path `a/b/c` has a filename of `c` and a folder name of `b`, it would appear to load `b/c`.
- `error` is called for *every* error. This is probably not what you want. It also does not return the load that caused the error.
- It is more normal to have a single callback, e.g. `void(^)(DSFolder*,NSError*)`.
- `finished` is unused. It looks like you want it to be called when the entire hierarchy has finished loading, which is Slightly Tricky.

Comment: The error block isn't safe for nil values yet, but thanks for pointing that out. And error handling isn't done. Yeah the finish block should be called when all files and folders are done. Do you have an idea how this could be programmed? Well the path thing is correct, the file hierarchy doesn't have a real a/b/c structure, it's made with database entries, the server knows how to handle it.